# The CreateAsync method neither throws an error nor updates the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-identity

I have the following simple code to create a new user using the `CreateAsync` method. The code does not throw any error but also does not update the database. I have added a breakpoint on the `IdentityResult result` line, where it stops, and another in the `if` statement, where it does not stop. As a result, I do not know how to debug this code and find the error. Any help?

```cs
public async Task<IdentityResult> Create(ApplicationUser user, string password)
{
    IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        throw new AppException("Failed");
    }

    return result;
}
```

This `Create` function is called from the controller:

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/ApplicationUser/Register")]
public IActionResult Register([FromBody]ApplicationUserDto userDto)
{
    //map dto to entity
    var user = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(userDto);

    try
    {
        // save 
        _userService.Create(user, userDto.Password);
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (AppException ex)
    {
        // return error message if there was an exception
        return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
    }   
}
```

The `Register` method is called from a React interface.

Comment: Have you verified that it's updating the proper database? Did you profile the code? Are there any other properties of `result` that may be helpful? Did you step through the code line by line with the debugger attached to make sure it even gets hit? There is the code calling your Create method?

Comment: @mason it stops in the line `IdentityResult result`. But, later does not stop although there is a breakpoint. Also `step into` debugging option does not visit the inside of `CreateAsync`.

Comment: you might be having a deadlock, how are you calling it?

Comment: @nalnpir I shared it in the OP.

Comment: have you tried adding ConfigureAwait(false) to the CreateAsync? Honestly im not sure whether this will work since your public method is synchronously and i think it returns before doing anything and thats why your code isnt executing at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never awaited your asynchronous call. Therefore it may not even complete by the time your action result returns and thus may never get run. Make sure you await any asynchronous calls. That means the calling method needs to be marked as async (and made to return a Task or Task), all the way up the call stack until it reaches an event handler or framework code. Here's what your code should look like:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/ApplicationUser/Register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]ApplicationUserDto userDto)
{
    //map dto to entity
    var user = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(userDto);

    try
    {
        // save 
        await _userService.Create(user, userDto.Password);
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (AppException ex)
    {
        // return error message if there was an exception
        return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
    }   
}
```

Also note that it's a bad idea to return exception details to the client user. Exceptions can contain sensitive information that an attacker can utilize to exploit your system. Instead, just return a generic "Sorry, something went wrong" message and log the exception details to your logging framework. If you don't have a logging framework, get one.